# Error installing STS 4.5.1 & Spring IDE Roo Support Will not be installed

Tags: java, spring, roo

I have STS 4.5.1 installed, I try to install Spring Roo 2.0.

I follow the steps of the sss website:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started-install-roo

4. Install Spring Roo

I continue step 1, step 2 ... until step 6.

Step 6 has substeps i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, vii

[Install window of STS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4h3L.png)

when I get to substep viii (I press the next button) I get:

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hExek.png)

The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Details:
  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.12.202003101511-CI-B2422 (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.12.202003101511-CI-B2422)
  Missing requirement: Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.12.202003101511-CI-B2422 (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group 3.9.12.202003101511-CI-B2422) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1' but it could not be found

Anyone know what happens
Thanks